# Python dataframe div function will not execuud

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working as a python newbie and having following problem.

Source table:

```
                  Timestamp Value
0      2022-01-31T23:00:37Z    79
1      2022-01-31T23:00:38Z    80
2      2022-01-31T23:00:39Z    79
3      2022-01-31T23:00:46Z    79
4      2022-01-31T23:00:47Z    80
...                     ...   ...
17181  2022-02-01T22:56:54Z    79
17182  2022-02-01T22:59:16Z    79
17183  2022-02-01T22:59:17Z    80
17184  2022-02-01T22:59:18Z    80
17185  2022-02-01T22:59:19Z    79

[17186 rows x 2 columns]
```

And want to divide it by a function with following code:

```
MAX = 79
SCALLING = 100
try: 
    cond = result['Value']>MAX
    result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result['Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)
except:
    result = result
print(result)
```

The function want divide the values.

I tried iterating over the dataframe in code:

```
MAX = 79
SCALLING = 100
for i in result.index: 
    cond = result['Value']>MAX
    result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result['Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)
print(result)
```

But then I got

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'.

Probably because `result.loc[cond,'Value']` is a dictionary datatype, how can I specify the specific value?

Comment: Is your goal to divide all `value`'s by 100 if they are larger than 79? Can you show what your output would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code, though not extremely "pythonic", actually works just fine with the data you've provided. E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Timestamp': {0: '2022-01-31T23:00:37Z',
  1: '2022-01-31T23:00:38Z',
  2: '2022-01-31T23:00:39Z',
  3: '2022-01-31T23:00:46Z',
  4: '2022-01-31T23:00:47Z'},
 'Value': {0: 79,
  1: 80,
  2: 79,
  3: 79,
  4: 80 }}

result = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(result)

              Timestamp  Value
0  2022-01-31T23:00:37Z     79
1  2022-01-31T23:00:38Z     80
2  2022-01-31T23:00:39Z     79
3  2022-01-31T23:00:46Z     79
4  2022-01-31T23:00:47Z     80

MAX = 79
SCALLING = 100
try: 
    cond = result['Value']>MAX
    result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result['Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)
except:
    result = result
print(result)

              Timestamp  Value
0  2022-01-31T23:00:37Z   79.0
1  2022-01-31T23:00:38Z    0.8
2  2022-01-31T23:00:39Z   79.0
3  2022-01-31T23:00:46Z   79.0
4  2022-01-31T23:00:47Z    0.8
```

However, this error message:

> 'TypeError' : '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'`

means that you have one or more `dict` values somewhere in `result.Value`.

E.g.:

```
data = {'Timestamp': {0: '2022-01-31T23:00:37Z',
  1: '2022-01-31T23:00:38Z',
  2: '2022-01-31T23:00:39Z',
  3: '2022-01-31T23:00:46Z',
  4: '2022-01-31T23:00:47Z'},
 'Value': {0: {'Value': 79},
  1: 80,
  2: 79,
  3: 79,
  4: 80 }}

result = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(result)

              Timestamp          Value
0  2022-01-31T23:00:37Z  {'Value': 79}
1  2022-01-31T23:00:38Z             80
2  2022-01-31T23:00:39Z             79
3  2022-01-31T23:00:46Z             79
4  2022-01-31T23:00:47Z             80
```

`result['Value']>MAX` would haved raised the aforementioned `TypeError`, if not for the `Try ... Except` construction.

So, the remedy is to find the `dict` values in your column, and deal with them. To locate them, you could use:

```
dict_values = result[result.Value.map(type)==dict]

print(dict_values)

              Timestamp          Value
0  2022-01-31T23:00:37Z  {'Value': 79}
```

Comment: As a sanity check OP should also run `result.dtypes`. The `Values` column should be "int64" but is probably "object"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer if your goal is to divide all `value`'s by SCALLING if they are larger than MAX. I don't know how you got a `dict` error. Maybe you have a dict called `MAX` somewhere?

```
import pandas as pd
import io

#Read in your example table
result = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO("""
                  Timestamp Value
0      2022-01-31T23:00:37Z    79
1      2022-01-31T23:00:38Z    80
2      2022-01-31T23:00:39Z    79
3      2022-01-31T23:00:46Z    79
4      2022-01-31T23:00:47Z    80
17181  2022-02-01T22:56:54Z    79
17182  2022-02-01T22:59:16Z    79
17183  2022-02-01T22:59:17Z    80
17184  2022-02-01T22:59:18Z    80
17185  2022-02-01T22:59:19Z    79
"""),
    delim_whitespace=True,
    index_col=0,
    parse_dates=['Timestamp'],
)


#Divide all value's by SCALLING if they are larger than MAX
MAX = 79
SCALLING = 100

cond = result['Value']>MAX
result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result.loc[cond,'Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)
print(result)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Unless the OP has duplicate index values (which, by the looks of it, seems rather unlikely), there is zero material difference between your `result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result.loc[cond,'Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)` and the OP's own `result.loc[cond,'Value'] = result['Value'].div(SCALLING).round(2)`. I.e. on the actual full set, this code will throw the exact same error.

Comment: you're right, there must be a dict in the dataframe to cause OP's error. I think that including the extra `loc` on the right-hand-side is better since it avoids doing divisions and rounding on rows with values below MAX. Unless pandas is being really smart and somehow avoiding these computations based on the index in the left-hand-side?

Comment: Good point. There might be computational gain. After fixing the `dict` problem, adding `.loc` might help the OP in optimizing. I'll have a look into that myself. Not sure how much difference that may or may not make. Always learning ;)